# when i open new page from appBar tabs, bottombar not hiding. Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm try to open some page from appbar tabs. I expect when i click the listView item, it will return a new page. It is return a new page but bottom bar not hiding. How can i fixed it? Maybe screenshots will help.[image]

[image]

And onTap method;

```
onTap: () {
           
            String kacinciAy = (index + 1).toString();
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Ay(
                  kacinciAy: kacinciAy,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
```

And my navBar codes

```
 return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 5,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(35),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(child: Container()),
                      TabBar(
                        tabs: [
                          Text("Günlük"),
                          Text("Takvim"),
                          Text("Hafta"),
                          Text("Ay"),
                          Text("Toplam")
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                GunlukVeri(context),
                Takvim(),
                Hafta(),
                Denek(),
                Column(
                  children: [Text("toplam")],
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Kindly share your code where you write the navbar widget

Comment: are you using nested navigation?

Comment: I added navbar codes. @Tasnuvaoshin

Comment: i dont know what is the nested navigation. I think i didn't use it. @reza